# Inserting a " overwrites the previous character when working in Citrix client

Tags: macos, keyboard

I run a Citrix viewer client to work in our companies hosted environment (Windows). When I want to insert an " in any application on the Citrix client the behaviour is as follows:

- type shift + " key
- type any other key
- the last character gets removed (as if one pressed backspace)
- type space key
- " character shows up

As a work around now I always enter an extra space before going to insert a ", but this isn't really a practical solution.

Keyboard is set to US-Int.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use US International, use US.

International on Windows uses the " key as a dead-key for an umlaut. If you type a key that can't take an umlaut… I'm not sure what happens, but I doubt it's what you would want.

Comment: Well the funny thing is I remember it used to work in the past. You'd just add a space after the " key to post the single character, or a character that doesn't accept an umlaut.

Comment: Yup, that's how it work when sitting at the machine - idk what Citrix will make of it, though.